# Error loading icons and fonts

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, font-awesome

anyone been through this problem.
Simply does not load the fonts

- Asp.net MVC4
- IIS 7
- Server amazon
- Css in Materialize and Fontawesome

Image Remote
[image: Remote image]

Image Local
[image: Local image]

Comment: Are your mime types set up properly in IIS to deliver the font files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have the proper mime types set in IIS.

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".eot" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-fontobject" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".ttf" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-woff" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

Source: http://codingstill.com/2013/01/set-mime-types-for-web-fonts-in-iis/

Alternatively, you can simply use a CDN, see: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/. That effectively side-steps the issue as your server isn't serving the font files any more.